# Prove that if $b,d \ne 0 \implies (a/b = c/d) \iff (ad = bc)$

Tags: calculus, propositional-calculus

In Chapter 1 of Spivak's Calculus (3rd Edition), problem 3, number (vi) it asks us to prove the following:

> If $b,d \ne 0$, then $$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} \iff ad = bc.$$
>   Determine when $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{b}{a}$.

So far, I have been able to prove all questions from this problem, but I really do not know how I should approach this one, when a proof gives me an *iff*. I have only worked on proofs of the form $p \implies q$.

I am not asking here to get a solution that I could copy to my notebook. I am sincerely interested on how should I do this proof since I am clueless about it. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Firstly, didn't you mean $ad=bc$?

Comment: Yes, a little mistake I made when typing. Thank you for the call.

Comment: Secondly, one way to deal with an "iff" type statement is to separate the proof into two parts, each of which is just a $\implies$ type problem. For example, suppose the fractions are equal. What could you do both sides to get the desired equality? For the converse, start with the equality. What could you do both sides to get the desired equality of fractions?

Comment: Show that ${a \over b} = {c \over d}$ implies $ad=bc$. This follows by multiplying through by $bd$. Then show that $ad=bc$ implies ${a \over b} = {c \over d}$. This follows by dividing through by $bd$.

Comment: You mean, proof that if a/b = c/d then a/b = ad and c/d = bc?

Comment: @MarcoI.Domínguez: You lost me there. I meant what I wrote.